# How do I know this blogspot is working?

Tags: blog, blogger

I am not sure if this is right place to ask this question...

I am not sure how this blog is working, I want to make a blog just like this:

[Search tk blog](http://searchtksites.blogspot.co.uk)

In a blog, I thought the only thing you can do is put text, pictures and videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a blog and then add widget with costum search

Comment: I tried it but this is not what that guy using in above blog, first he is only checking dot.tk domains, second results are on same blog, but if I add a custom google search widget in my blog I just tried to  search and it took me to google search

Comment: maybe you need to check and copy his source code to your template and start with that.

Comment: I thought about that, but its too much to copy, I think he might developed a gadget that does that